# Laravel WebSockets. Issue with App key. How it fix?

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, real-time-updates

I can start websocket on

```
php artisan websockets:serve
```

But when i try to open my site page it says that

```
New connection opened for app key websocketkey.
Exception `BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\WebSockets\Exceptions\UnknownAppKey` thrown: `Could not find app key `websocketkey`.`
Unknown app id: exception `BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\WebSockets\Exceptions\UnknownAppKey` thrown: `Could not find app key `websocketkey`.`.
Connection id  sending message {"event":"pusher:error","data":{"message":"Could not find app key `websocketkey`.","code":4001}}
Connection id  closed.
Exception `ErrorException` thrown: `Undefined property: Ratchet\Server\IoConnection::$app`
```

In config/websockets.php i got app key from env

```
'apps' => [
    [
        'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'enable_client_messages' => true,
        'enable_statistics' => true,
    ],
],
```

I don't understand where getting `websocketkey` from. Because there are no such values in env.
I try `php artisan config:clear` and it didn't help.
Please share who knows how to solve this and why it happens at all.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the websocket worked for me, while `php artisan config:clear` did not.

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer